# Sending Programmatic Mouse Events to X

Tags: c++, linux, user-interface, cursor, xorg

I am somewhat new to `X` development on Linux. I'm wondering what are best practices (or links to resources) for programmatically sending cursor events. Moving the cursor to a normalized (X,Y), creating right/left mouse clicks, etc. Ideally this would be something in `C/C++`.

I have played around with the Qt `QCursor` but I'd like to know the raw way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use [`XSendEvent`](http://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/event-handling/XSendEvent.html). There's some sample code [here](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/simulating-a-mouse-click-594576/#post2936738) which uses [`XQueryPointer`](http://www.xfree86.org/4.4.0/XQueryPointer.3.html) to populate most of the event fields.

If you just want to move the pointer, use [`XWarpPointer`](http://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/input/XWarpPointer.html).

Comment: This looks promising. Thank you.

Comment: XWarpPointer() and XTest seem to require calling XFlush() to get immediate results. Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to be learning Xlib if you want the "raw" way to accomplish it.

If you want even MORE raw, you'll want to study the X protocol.

What you're asking about is pretty darn specialized knowledge.  You should head over to the X.org mailing lists or X related newsgroups.

Comment: Thanks for the suggest I'll hit that up.

Answer (score 1):

Also check out xdotool

http://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/